# Dot/inner product between mixed types in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra

I am trying to implement a logistic regression algorithm of my own in R, and I can't seem to make the matrix multiplication/dot product operator `%*%` work. I have tried quite a few different things. Below is code that should be runnable in an R environment:

```
weight_a <- c(rep(1,5))
random_sample <- sample(1:NROW(iris),50)
# Delta terms for each type (starts out nonzero)
del_a <- 1;

# Dataset for part a (first 50 vs. last 100)
iris_a <- iris
iris_a$Species <- as.integer(iris_a$Species)
# Convert list to binary class
for (i in 1:NROW(iris_a$Species)) {if (iris_a$Species[i] != "1") {iris_a$Species[i] <- -1}}

while(del_a > 0.01) {
# Compute gradient
  for (k in 1:NROW(random_sample)) {
    grade_a <- -1/NROW(random_sample) * sum(iris_a$Species[random_sample[k]]*iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4]
                                        /(1+exp(iris_a$Species[random_sample[k]]*weight_a%*%iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4])))
  }
}
```

The critical part is `weight_a%*%iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4]`, which doesn't work (translated into English, the error is "Matrix or vector is required"). So I tried a few other things:

```
# Trivial case works, gives 5
rep(1,5)%*%rep(1,5)

# Gives tensor product
rep(1,5)%*%as.matrix(iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4])

# Transpose doesn't work, gives row vector and result is an error ("Improper argument").
t(t(rep(1,5)))%*%as.matrix(iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4])
# Double transpose gives column vector, but result is tensor product again
t(t(rep(1,5)))%*%as.matrix(iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4])

# Matrix context gives tensor product again
as.matrix(rep(1,5))%*%as.matrix(iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4])
# Transposing the first argument to get a row vector gives an "Improper argument" error again
t(as.matrix(rep(1,5)))%*%as.matrix(iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4])
```

R is supposed to be smarter than this (and better than MATLAB). Assuming that I'm just doing it wrong, what's the right way to make this work? (I rolled my own looped function, but, ugh...)

Comment: Sigh, this is a lesson in sanity checking. The length of the `weight_a` vector is 5, while the feature vector `iris_a[...]` is 4. Coding late at night is not always a recipe for success... The winning code line is `weight_a%*%t(iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `weight_a%*%iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4]` doesn't work because of two reasons:

(1) The lengths of your objects differ, and (2) `iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4]` is not numeric:

```
weight_a
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 #5 values
mode(weight_a)
[1] "numeric" #ok

iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
74          6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 #four values

mode(iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4])
   [1] "list" #wrong type!
```

So the lengths of your vectors differ and also the second argument is not numeric. This should work:

```
weight_a[-5]%*%as.numeric(iris_a[random_sample[k],1:4]) 
     [,1]
[1,] 14.8
#or you could just make weight_a<-rep(1,4)
```

edit: the original code in question was from `0:4`, changed the answer to correspond new code.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized the weight vector is too long. Also, the mode change is way better than my hacking away with the t() function. Thanks for the quick answer; this kind of thing frustrates me.